# JAVA - Two clients java with SSL connection, first need certificate, second doesn't need certificate

Tags: java, rest, ssl, certificate, rest-client

I have a Java project built with myEclipse, Java 1.7. Project call two clients that make Rest request on two different SSL web services end-point.

```
..
public void Example() {
..
CallFirstClient();
CallSecondClient();
..
}
```

First client need certificate, second client doesn't need certificate. 
If I execute second client alone, it work without certificate.
In first client I load certificate and it work:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", pathKeyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", pathKeyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
```

After execution of first client (with certificate), second doesn't work because have problem with certificate (but it doesn't need!).

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I tried to clear, into the second client, system properties:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "false");
System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword");
System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
```

But it doesn't work. 
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Changing these system properties after they have been set and used accomplishes nothing, as they have already been read into variables that won't be changed. Your keystore and truststore should be set up the same for both servers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The second client is developed with **Java 1.6** that **doesn't make control** about certificate of SSL connection. So, when I execute the client alone without keystore, it work!

My Java project (Example) is developed with **Java 1.7** that **make control** about certificate. So, the solution is:

1. **download the certificate from server** - End-point of second client (Google Chrome, click on padlock, download certificate .cer format)
2. **add certificate to keystore**
3. **The second client work**

Comment: Java 1.6 'makes the same control' about SSL  certificates as every other version. Adding the server certificate to your keystore doesn't make anything work. Adding it to your *truststore* might, but only if the server had a self-signed certificTe.